# Google Apps Script - send pdf in email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I have a script that sends an email. I would like to set it up so that the email is sent with a pdf attachment that is in my google drive. The name of the file is pdfholder.pdf

Here is the code that is **currently working** (without attachment), and sending emails

```
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message);
```

Here is the code that is **not working** (with the attachment), and not sending emails

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById('pdfholder');
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message, {attachments:file});
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? I am new to google apps scripting so simple/thorough explanations would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The argument needed for the optional argument attachment is an array (as clearly shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29)).
This is to allow for easy handling of multiple attached files. In you case it will be an array of one single element : [file]
so your final code would (indeed) be

```
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message, {attachments:[file]});
```

Comment: "no offense but this kind of question needs more than just a line of code... a word of explanation and/or a link to the doc is IMHO often necessary for "non-expert" askers." – Serge insas 
/ 
William Chiquito says: Totally agree. Unfortunately I did not count with enough time to give a more elaborate answer to the question, so I put the code only. On future occasions will avoid this type of answers. Thank you. I deleted my answer.

Comment: I am using GmailApp. Everything works well , but when we download the attached file. it is downloaded as "File Type" rather "PDF type".  What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The official doc has an example exactly for this purpose too:

```
// Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Insert any HTML content here', 'text/html', 'my_document.html');
 MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app