# Google App Script not Creating PDF from Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I've completed a fairly standard Google Form to Sheet to Doc to PDF with the code below, but the PDF portion is not working (the Doc is created correctly but the PDF isn't created or saved anywhere, and it subsequently never makes it to the email) - I have tried so many variations from StackOverflow and YouTube with no success. I'm sure I'm missing something basic but any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {

  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var address = e.values[3];
  var email = e.values[4];
  var age = e.values[5];
  var loanBalance = e.values[6];
  var repaymentDuration = e.values[7];
  var pipaConsent = e.values[8];
  var agreement = e.values[9];
  var telephoneNumber = e.values[10];
  var periodicPaymentAmount = e.values[11];
  var deferralFee = e.values[12];
  var downpaymentAmount = e.values[13];
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('File-ID'); 
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder-ID');
  var dtStr = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd");
  var copy = file.makeCopy(dtStr + '\t-\t' + firstName + '\t' + lastName, folder); 
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', firstName);  
  body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', lastName); 
  body.replaceText('{{Address}}', address); 
  body.replaceText('{{Email Address}}', email); 
  body.replaceText('{{Age}}', age);
  body.replaceText('{{Loan Balance}}', loanBalance); 
  body.replaceText('{{Repayment Duration}}', repaymentDuration); 
  body.replaceText('{{PIPA Consent}}', pipaConsent); 
  body.replaceText('{{Agreement}}', agreement); 
  body.replaceText('{{Telephone Number}}', telephoneNumber); 
  body.replaceText('{{Periodic Payment Amount}}', periodicPaymentAmount); 
  body.replaceText('{{Deferral Fee}}', deferralFee); 
  body.replaceText('{{Downpayment Amount}}', downpaymentAmount); 
  
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
  
  var pdfBlob = doc.getAs('application/pdf').setName(doc.getName() + '.pdf');
  
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
    
  var subject = 'Welcome to ####';
  var message = 'Thank you,\t' + firstName + '\t' + lastName + '\t for choosing ####';
  var agreement = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfBlob.getId());
  
  MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[agreement]});
}
```

Comment: I think that `pdfBlob` can be used for the attachment file. So how about removing `var agreement = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfBlob.getId());` and modifying `MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[agreement]});` to `MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[pdfBlob]});`?

Comment: I think that this official document might be also useful for your situation. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your input. While I'm not getting the email with PDF attachment, I think the issue is earlier in the creation of the PDF - it doesn't get created and saved anywhere on my Drive - I need it to be created in the same drive folder as the Doc. Not sure where to go from here (albeit I've made the blob changes to the email for later).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about ` I think the issue is earlier in the creation of the PDF`. I would like to confirm your situation. In that case, can you confirm the copied file by `var copy = file.makeCopy(dtStr + '\t-\t' + firstName + '\t' + lastName, folder);`? By the way, I think that in your case, an error might occur. So if you see the error message, can you provide it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem (at least one of them) is that your code is adding an file object instead of a blob object

```
var agreement = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfBlob.getId());
```

The above line assigns a file object to `agreement` but we need blob. As you already assigned a blob to `pdfBlob`, replace

```
MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[agreement]});
```

by

```
MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[pdfBlob]});
```

Related

- [Blob attachments in MailApp.sendEmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13238548/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script - send pdf in email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18213099/1595451)
- [Updated doc not attaching as pdf in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35603635/1595451)
- [Saving Sheet to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52291705/1595451)
- [I need to use a newly merged document to create a pdf, add it to a specific gdrive folder, note the pdf url on GSheet, then delete merged GDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56571737/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to end like this:

```
var fi=folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
var subject = 'Welcome to ####';
var message = 'Thank you,\t' + firstName + '\t' + lastName + '\t for choosing ####';
MailApp.sendEmail (email, subject, message, {attachments:[fi]});
```